Specific, practical examples of limits of logic gate fan-in?
I've been looking around for discrete, specific, and practical answers to the question "how many inputs can a (N)AND/(N)OR gate have?" as it relates to ASIC/VLSI/MOSFET/semiconductor technology. The only answers I've found are the theoretical "as many as you want/are willing to pay for" and the vague "it depends on your technology." I'm aware of this.
What I'm looking for is essentially: If I wanted an ASIC manufactured with a combinational logic circuit containing wide/high fan-in logic gates, what multi-input gates are available for me to build this out of? Let's say my circuit needs a 64-input OR gate. Sure, I could make a binary tree of 2-input OR gates, but could I do better? If a 4-input OR gate built directly as a multi-input gate is cheaper and/or faster than a tree of three 2-input OR gates, then it would be better for me to use those as a base instead. For instance, if a standard 2-input OR gate requires 6 CMOS transistors, the tree would require 18. If a 4-input OR gate can be built using less than 18 transistors, then I would prefer to use that.
The type of answer I'm looking for is something like this: Fab X can build a 4-input OR gate with 12 CMOS transistors. Here's a link to a specification document or whitepaper verifying that this is possible using their 28 nm technology.
I'd also be grateful for tips on what to look for or where to find answers. I've scoured this site (and similar forums), IEEEXplore, Google (Scholar), and just about any other venue I can think of for anything related to "high fan-in logic gates" and similar keywords but have come up essentially empty.
I'll also note that I'm looking at micro/nanoscale semiconductor technologies in particular, e.g., MOSFET rather than (for lack of a better description) breadboard-style components, so answers like "this exists!" won't really help me (that is, unless I have a basic misunderstanding around what scale these things can be made for).
The reason why I'm asking this is because I need to know what number of inputs I can practically and realistically have on a logic gate (specifically OR, but I'm also curious about (N)AND/NOR). From there I can analyze the complexity and critical path of larger OR gates constructed out of trees of this unit, similar to the example I provided above. As for why I need to do this, the best answer I can provide is that it's for a research project, and I thought it would be worth asking to see if someone here could point me in the right direction to finding this information. I'm not asking for someone to solve my base research problem, nor will I disclose what it is. Other than what's mentioned above, I don't have any particular special requirements.
For additional context, I'm familiar with FPGA technology, but not nearly as much with ASIC/VLSI/MOSFET etc. I know that I can write HDL to generate an OR gate with any number of inputs, and the results are limited by the physical LUTs on the FPGA. What I want to know is how this translates to non-programmable logic/ASIC.

well, on an FPGA, it's limited by the structure of the FPGA's LUTs. That's not the same as what you can do in a VLSI design.

Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask±". the come back and [edit] your question to clarify. -- Why do you need to know? -- What are the other requirements? (For example, with an FPGA or ASIC you are only limited by the number of pins, if you don't have other requirements.)

I can't tell if the question is focused on logic cells in FPGAs or if it is supposed to be a sweeping vista that goes all the way back to mechanical logic. Regardless, semiconductor based logic ... at some point ... was standardized -- had written standards of behavior a designer could rely upon and that a manufacturer would guarantee by design and theory. Does this question include what possibilities are available beyond any given standard? I'm not sure.

Thanks for your feedback, all.
@Hearth I'm aware that FPGA and VLSI are fundamentally different. I have a pretty good idea of how it works on FPGA, but I want to know how it works on ASIC/VLSI/semiconductor technology. That's why I'm asking this question. I don't need answers about FPGA unless it's to help me understand the VLSI part. I only mentioned FPGA to provide context for what I already know and why I'm asking the question. I've edited my question to help clarify this.

@thebusybee Thanks for the information. I've edited my question to clarify as best I can. Let me know if anything else seems unclear.

@periblepsis I'm asking specifically about ASIC/VLSI/semiconductor logic. I've edited my question to clarify that a bit better. The standards that you mentioned are part of the answer I am seeking - when I say "practical" I mean "what's actually available in the real world" instead of "what would be possible beyond the standard?" because the answer to the latter is "essentially anything if you want to pay for it" as far as I'm aware.

@MaxwellPhillips I wasn't addressing something that could be answered with "essentially anything if you want to pay for it". That's obvious. I was addressing the case, such as the 74AC family, for example. Not where you would contract to generate a new 74ACX family that met your specs. But where you have to live with the specs that already exist for the 74AC. I was pointing out that there is a standard for that family. There are also many possibilities beyond the standard that are not guaranteed, but that may work fine. You might be asking about the part that exceeds specs but still works.
